# USERNAME PRINTING NULL; javabeans, jsp session

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Username is printing NULL, what is the problem here in realtion to the servlet and jsp page. please note i am using javabean here too. i am using same session attribute twice with the bean db.

SERVLET ONE

```
    if(userPassword!=null && userPassword.equals(password)) {

   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   BookingBean db = (BookingBean)session.getAttribute("formData"); //use existing session
   if(db == null) {
   db = new BookingBean(); }

   db.setUsername(username);
   session.setAttribute("formData", db);
  getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/BookingForm.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } else ......
```

SERVLET TWO

```
     HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    if(!session.isNew()){

        db = new BookingBean();
        db.setRandom();
        db.setAdult(adults);
        db.setChildren(children);
        db.setOap(oap);
        db.setEmail(email);
        db.setDate(date);
        db.setLocation(loc);
        db.setPromo(promo);
        db.setTime(time);
        db.setfirstName(firstName);
        db.setsurName(surname);
        db.setTotal();
        session.setAttribute("formData", db);


    } 



 JSP PAGE


    <jsp:useBean id="formData" class="bean.BookingBean" scope ="session">

    </jsp:useBean>

    <%BookingBean username = (BookingBean)session.getAttribute("formData");
        if(username==null)  {
                        // if session is expired, forward it to login page

     %>
     <jsp:forward page="Login.jsp" />
    <%}%>

    <p>Confirmation of Booking for the following user: <%=formData.getUsername()%><p><br><br>
```

Comment: Can you provide your jsp code ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like both your servlets create a new BookingBean when invoked:

```
db = new BookingBean();
```

So, when you store it to the session under key `"formData"`, the BookingBean stored by the other servlet gets overwritten. Instead, you need to first check if the session already contains the bean, and create a new one only if there's not one stored in the session.

Here's a simple way to check if the session already has this object:

```
BookingBean db = (BookingBean)session.getAttribute("formData");

//HttpSession will return null, if there is no object with the given key
if(db == null)
{
    db = new BookingBean();
}

//Continue as before...
```

Comment: exactly what is happening, would you be able to show me how to do that in a if statement?

Comment: @user1106130: You edited my answer, not your question ;) I moved your edits to your question. Anyway, looks like you're not storing the BookingBean in the session with `formData`-key, but instead the username itself. Change `session.setAttribute("formData", username);` to `session.setAttribute("formData", db);` and change the line `<%String username = (String)session.getAttribute("formData");` in jsp to `<%BookingBean username = (BookingBean)session.getAttribute("formData");`.

Comment: That didnt do the trick, it still shows null after i modified. and sorry for the mistake editing your answer lool.

Comment: Hard to say what's exactly wrong here, at least your "servlet two" seems to be still writing a new BookingBean into the Session with name "formData" without checking if one already exists. You could try printing out more values of formData in your jsp, to see if they are all null or just some are set. If your "servlet two" is called before the jsp-view, it will have again overwritten the existing BookingBean with a one that has an unset username.

Comment: i tried printing formData values, it printed all servlet two values email firstname etc, but not servlet one values

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using two different object for your data. Make sure, that you are only using one object. Every servlet should check, if the attribute is already set with a BookingBean instance and use this instance.

Make sure, that you are synchronizing the session object:

```
synchronized (request.getSession().getId().intern()) { 
//dosomething
}
```

Comment: thanks for you help, but i am not allowed to use getId, intern etc at this stage, but the problem does lie with creating same object twice.

Comment: Without that you could run into some racing conditions checking for the existence of the object and setting it.